# using tab and carriage return character in a WPF resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

How can I use tab and carriage return characters in a WPF XAML resource dictionary?

This doesn't work for me:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
                >

<system:String x:Key="test_Key">Tab doesnt work\tTest\rTest</system:String>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

when I retrieve this via FindResource("test_key"), both the tab and carriage return characters are removed.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The XAML parser uses whitespace normalisation (as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189036%28VS.95%29.aspx#whitespace)) if you want to avoid this add `xml:space="preserve"` to your XML as such:

```
<system:String x:Key="test_Key" xml:space="preserve">Tab doesnt work&#x09;Test&#x0d;Test</system:String>
```

Comment: `\t` and such are never converted to special characters, if you use the preserve option you should actually write a tab and a carriage return.

Comment: Oops, forgot to switch the characters around to encoded ones.

Answer (score 23):

Add newline like so `&#x0d;&#x0a;` and tab with `&#x09;`

However this won't work unless you've turned off white-space normalization as J.Kommer suggests

Comment: You appear to have the order "wrong", that's a carriage return followed by a line feed. (And the question was about a carriage return not a new line)

Comment: @H.B. Carriage return is \r = 13 = #x0d and new line is \r\n so my order is "correct".