# How to place tabs into a WPF ListBox?

Tags: wpf

How do I one place tabs? with

```
   <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxContents" />
```

in an xaml?  Tabs at locations 20 and 50 in that ListBox. The ListBox text is Name\tAddress\tCity.

Comment: 'Tabbing' is *not* the way to go. Instead, define a [`DataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521(v=vs.110).aspx) that describes what your `ListBoxItem` should look like. You can then use `Grid` columns to represent your 'tabs'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found relevant info at: [Multicolumn ListBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911026/multicolumn-listbox-in-wpf) -> the second answer describes using a ListBox.  Below is the code I added ... it works.

```
public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  List<ListBoxItems> items = new List<ListBoxItems>();
  items.Add(new ListBoxItems() { ColumnOneText = "First LIne", ColumnTwoText = "  45", ColumnThreeText = "  End" });
  items.Add(new ListBoxItems() { ColumnOneText = "Line 2", ColumnTwoText = "  45 ,,, 2", ColumnThreeText = "  End -> 2" });
  items.Add(new ListBoxItems() { ColumnOneText = "Line 3", ColumnTwoText = "  45 ,,,,,, 3", ColumnThreeText = "  End -> 3" });
  gLBxDb2.ItemsSource = items;
  }
}
public class ListBoxItems
{
    public string ColumnOneText { get; set; }
    public string ColumnTwoText { get; set; }
    public string ColumnThreeText { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use character `&#x09;` and the attribute `xml:space="preserve"` as described here:

[using tab and carriage return character in a WPF resource dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835260/using-tab-and-carriage-return-character-in-a-wpf-resource-dictionary)

To replace the `\t` by `&#x09;` you can use a ValueConverter in your binding:

```
public class TabConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is string)
        {
            return value.ToString().Replace("\t", "&#x09;");
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if(value is string)
        {
            return value.ToString().Replace("&#x09;", "\t");
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

The binding in the listbox might be as follows:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding NameAndAddress Converter=TabConverter}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Suggesting using another character suggests modifying the model to accomodate the view. We're of course not discussing MVVM here, but that's something to point out in my opinion.

Comment: Your are right, I interpreted the above text as an example. If the data contains \t characters, they should be converted by a ValueConverter. I've modified my answer accordingly.

Comment: Where do I place <ListBox.ItemTemplate>? The compiler doesn't like this regardless of where I place it.  Also, is NameAndAddress used anywhere else?

Comment: Ignore the first part ... typo.  Is NameAndAddress used anywhere else?